# How to get a specific value from drop-down list

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following html:

```
<td>
    {%verbatim%}
    <select ng-model="s_value" class="form-control">
        <option ng-repeat="s in severity_list" ng-value="s.rank" >{{s.rank}}-{{s.generic_value}}</option>
    {%endverbatim%}
    </select>
</td>
```

I need to only display the rank(integer value) in my form/table. But its actually getting both the integer and string value into the field. How can I prevent that and only display the integer value? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

As per going through the answers I have updated my question with the severity_list, Is there any changes because of the edit guys?

```
$scope.severity_lists = function(){
            console.log('Stage1: Loading Sods..... ');
            $http.get('{% url "severities"  %}').success(
                function(data){
                    $scope.severity_list = data['objects'];
            }).error(function(data, status){
                    console.log('Stage1: Internal error while loading initial data:'+status );
            });
        };
        $scope.severity_lists();
```

Editted to display the problem to SK:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use ng-options really

edit: read your other comment and realised you might want this

```js
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.severity_list = [{
        rank: 1,
        generic_value: 'severe'
      }, {
        rank: 2,
        generic_value: 'not so bad'
      }];

      $scope.initialiseOptions = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.severity_list.length; i++) {
          $scope.severity_list[i].Text = $scope.severity_list[i].rank + '-' + $scope.severity_list[i].generic_value;
        }
      }

      $scope.initialiseOptions();
      $scope.dropdownChanged = function() {
        if($scope.s_value){
          $scope.initialiseOptions(); // reset our previous selections         
          $scope.s_value.Text = $scope.s_value.rank;// Set our display to only rank after its chosen
        }        
      };

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <select ng-model="s_value" class="form-control" ng-options="option as option.Text for option in severity_list" ng-change="dropdownChanged()">
  </select>

  Selected:{{s_value}}

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the comments, I can suggest something like the following?

It's not brilliant but it demonstrates an approach, here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LXAt7/573/

`<select ng-model="s_value" class="form-control"  ng-hide="!editMode" ng-options="s.rank as (s.rank + ' - ' + s.generic_value) for s in severity_list" ng-change="valueChanged()">
</select>
<input type="text" ng-model="s_value" ng-show="!editMode" ng-click="changeToEditMode()" />`

It's worth noting that using `ng-options` is a cleaner approach. - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

I'm not familiar with this verbatim tag, but it does seem out of position, should it not be below the `</select>`?

Comment: Daniel, I want to display both rank and generic_value as drop-downs(ex: 1-High), BUt once the user select the option, I want to only display the rank in the field

Comment: That sounds odd, so when you click the drop down, it displays different data to after selection?

Comment: When I click the drop-down --> Display both rank and generic value

Comment: After I click the drop-down --> The value I want to display in my input field must be rank

Comment: One option would be to display an input text with the s_value next to the dropdown, and ng-show it only when it has a value? Perhaps hiding the dropdown when it does have a value and having an edit button to change the value?

Comment: As per my edit, would that work having another input? This assumes they may want to change the value

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this. I've tried to keep it simple:

```js
var app = angular.module("Demo", []);

 app.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
   $scope.severity_list = [{
     rank: 1,
     generic_value: "High"
   }, {
     rank: 2,
     generic_value: "Mid"
   }, {
     rank: 3,
     generic_value: "Low"
   }];

   $scope.getVal = function(ind) {
     if ($scope.selectedValue != undefined && $scope.selectedValue == $scope.severity_list[ind].rank) {
       $scope.severity_list[ind].viewValue = $scope.severity_list[ind].rank;
     } else {
       $scope.severity_list[ind].viewValue = $scope.severity_list[ind].rank + '-' + $scope.severity_list[ind].generic_value;
     }
     return $scope.severity_list[ind].viewValue;
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Demo">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <select ng-model="selectedValue">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option ng-repeat="s in severity_list" value="{{s.rank}}">
        {{ getVal($index) }}</option>
    </select>
    <span ng-show="selectedValue">Selected Value: {{ selectedValue }} </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sktajbir/6fmvsaf0/21/

Here selected value will be always rank because of this code in the option tag:

```
value="{{s.rank}}"
```

If you want full object as selected object then you can try:

```
value="{{s}}"
```

I hope this will help you to think further. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sk what actually `changeVal()`?

Comment: ohh sorry about that. First I thought a way using ng-change but later the purpose was achieved without ng-option but I forgot to remove it. I've edited above code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a bunch SK, it worked. But one new problem also come up. Lets say if I select the value 2 and after that I want to select 4; when I come to select for 4, the generic_value corresponds to 2(which i previously selected) is missing. Means the generic_value of my previous selection is always gone missing once i choose another option from the drop-down

Comment: Can you please go and edit the jsfiddle link with your value so that I can get a clear view of your problem? Then update the jsFiddle and send it to me. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how I can edit this, because there is no problem with the code. Its only something missing in your script. Can't rectify whats that. I edited my question with a screenshot of the current problem :)

Comment: As u can see, I selected 9 before. When I come back again to the drop-dwon the value is missing some how

Comment: as you've selected 9, in the dropdown list it will always show 9. This is how html select option works. If I change the value back to 9-something on opening the dropdown list then the showing value will change to 9-something as well. For that kind of approach you have to create a custom html control.

Comment: Same solution as provided by Lee but poorly implemented. Additionally, it's bad practice to use ng-repeat on options due to binding issues you may encounter later on

Comment: @Daniel: What binding issue are you talking about? can you give me any reference. Also there are some implementation difference between my solution and Lee's solution.

Comment: @Sk.Tajbir - Just read the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: @Daniel: I've read this doc but for small operation like this, I don't think it will create much effect and as it will not effect much, so I think its better to concentrate on simple approach. Anyway thanks for your concern. I'll research more on ng-repeat's usage on options. +1 for giving me the link and make me think again regarding this kind of approach. Thank you :)

Comment: @Sk.Tajbir No problem, I did encounter issues with binding integers back to these values also, because the `value={{s.rank}}` will be a string. Not sure if that has been remedied in newer versions of angular. I recommend using ng-options, the syntax is clearer and more concise, and it performs better.